# Finding specific Exceptions using Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using `VS 2010 Express` for `VB.net` and wondering if there is an easy way to discover exceptions that I might encounter by using the IDE?

For example if I have the following:

```
If Me.saveQueryDialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Try
        sqlTextBox.SaveFile(saveQueryDialog.FileName)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Save was unsuccessful encountered: {0}", ex.Message))
    End Try
End If
```

Can I use the IDE to somehow find that the usual exception I'll encounter in this circumstance is `...ex As IO.IOException`

Or in the following:

```
If Me.openQueryDialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Try
        sqlTextBox.LoadFile(openQueryDialog.FileName)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Open was unsuccessful encountered: {0}", ex.Message))
    End Try
End If
```

..the most common exception I'll encounter is `...ex As IO.FileLoadException`

Or do I need to just try to remember these specific exceptions?

Comment: You can check the MSDN Documentation for the functions that you are using: it tells any possible exception a method can throw

Comment: @SysDragon so it'd be the documentation for either `Savefile` or `Loadfile` ?

Comment: @whytheq: Do you want you IDE to break at a Specific exception, when in Debug mode?

Comment: @jacobaloysious no - all I want is to be more specific than `Catch ex As Exception`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4a710b1.aspx) for each method that you are using to see any possible exception they can throw.

[image: PossibleExceptionsExample]

This, for example, are the possible exceptions for `.SaveFile()` method.